# dig not returning answer for domain registered with namecheap?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-name, dig, namecheap

Running `dig chimu.sh`

Results in the following:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> chimu.sh
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 14376
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;chimu.sh.          IN  A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 29 02:20:05 EDT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 37
```

I have registered the domain with namecheap, and have the following values:

[image]

My assumption is that `dig` should return something. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

Comment: `dig chimu.sh` returns perfectly fine from here.

Comment: Is it possible that my `dig` is cached somehow, and I need to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes. Wait for a few hours and try again, or try a different ns with `dig chimu.sh @1.1.1.1` for instance

Comment: The records [look fine](https://www.nslookup.io/domains/chimu.sh/dns-records/#authoritative). You're probably hit by 'negative caching', i.e. your DNS resolver cached the fact that the domain didn't exist. Clearing this cache depends on your OS, but there are plenty of tutorials online.